# Change placement of "exporting" option

Tags: highcharts, positioning

I'd like to change the placement of the "exporting" buttons. In the moment they are positioned at the top right, and thus hiding pieces of a longer title. I'd like to change that, but don't see in the references a parameter for that.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many options to style buttons, you just have to take a look the reference.

Using `exporting`, you can directly style the button, like:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        exportButton: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 40
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/8457/)

Using `navigation` you can style all buttons:

```
navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
        align: 'center'
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/4/)

*Reference*:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#exporting.buttons.exportButton

Comment: Ok, I see that I need to then do this for the "exportButton" and "printButton" separately. I thought they would be treated as one entity. Thanks!

Comment: Cool answer, but the links to the demo didn't work for me

Answer (score 6):

Ricardo's answer is almost correct. I believe the syntax has changed since he answered.

[exporting button documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#exporting.buttons.contextButton)

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            contextButton: {
                align: 'left',
                x: 0,
                y: 380,
                verticalAlign: 'top'
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      align: 'center',
      x: 50
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use x/y or align parameter: [ExportButton Align](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.exportButton.align)